# yum Cannot open: oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping

Tags: centos, yum, oracle

I am following [this](https://voidtech.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/centos-6-install-and-configure-oracle-client/) article on installing the oracle client RPMs on a CentOs 6.x server using yum localinstall.for some reason yum cannot open the RPMs - and I am at a loss as to what the next step should be.

```
[me@somewhere oracle-install-files]$ ls -l

total 24
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 5307 Feb 12 11:35 oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 5307 Feb 12 11:35 oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 5307 Feb 12 11:35 oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm

[me@somewhere oracle-install-files]$ sudo yum localinstall oracle* --nogpgcheck

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Local Package Process
Cannot open: oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Cannot open: oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Cannot open: oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do
```

I tried pathing them out individually like this:

```
sudo yum localinstall oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck
```

similar error (but only for the individual rpms).

well.. ...you canot wghet these files directly.  They need to be "approved"

Comment: Those are probably not RPMs, but the HTML page asking you to accept the license agreement...

Comment: yup exactly.  live..learn...

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably not RPMs, but the HTML page asking you to accept the license agreement. The fact that they were all exactly 5307 bytes should have been a major clue. That's the size of a web page, not the software you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the disablerepo option to prevent yum from searching through online repositories

```
sudo yum localinstall --disablerepo=* oracle* --nogpgcheck
```

Comment: unfortunately, that is not it.